# Checkbox copies range(s) of merged rows into new workbook, but how to ignore hidden columns in specified range(s) when copying over?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that is VERY close. It has a few minor kinks that I cannot figure out.

Please see screenshot below to understand what this code does. If column S has a checkmark, the code takes all the checked specified merged ranges, and copies over to a new workbook. (See green ranges in photo)
[image]

1. However, in some situations, certain columns can be hidden, and I don't want to copy that range over when column is hidden (see red ranges in photo).
   [image]

I have tried so many methods of if-then or if-ifelse statements and none work. I tried making two multiplerange application.Unions, but I am having predefined range issues the way I currently have the code set up.

2. The checkboxes are populating in opposite order. So If I select item 1,2,3,4 it ports over the rows in completely wrong order 2,3,4,1. I think this may be due to the naming order of the checkbox objects?

```
Sub copySelected()
'Upon clicking export to customer button, specific ranges and checked box values in column T are exported to new workbook
Dim shtSource As Worksheet
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim cb As CheckBox
Dim destRow As Long

Set shtSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RFQ FORM INT") 'where the data is
Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add
Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")

   'Copy values and formats of range A1:F14
    shtSource.Range("A1:F12").Copy
    wsDest.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    wsDest.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
   'Copy values and formats of range G10:H10
    shtSource.Range("G10:H10").Copy
    wsDest.Range("R11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    'Copy values and formats of range G12:I14
    shtSource.Range("B13:I14").Copy
    wsDest.Range("B13").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    wsDest.Range("B13").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
 'Copy values and formats of range K12:M14
    shtSource.Range("K13:M14").Copy
    wsDest.Range("J13").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    wsDest.Range("J13").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    'Copy values and formats of range P12:R14
    shtSource.Range("P13:R14").Copy
    wsDest.Range("M13").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    wsDest.Range("M13").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    'Copy values and formats of range Y12:AB14
    shtSource.Range("Y12:AB14").Copy
    wsDest.Range("P12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    wsDest.Range("P12").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    'Copy values and formats of range AF12:AG14
    shtSource.Range("AF12:AG14").Copy
    wsDest.Range("T12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    wsDest.Range("T12").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
      'Copy values and formats of range AI12:AJ14
    shtSource.Range("AI12:AJ14").Copy
    wsDest.Range("V12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    wsDest.Range("V12").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
destRow = 15 ' starting row in the destination sheet

For Each cb In shtSource.CheckBoxes 'loop through all checkboxes
    If cb.Value = 1 Then 'if the checkbox has been selected then...
        ' Figure out the area of data we want to copy
        Dim sourceRange1 As Range, sourceRange2 As Range, sourceRange3 As Range, sourceRange4 As Range, sourceRange5 As Range, sourceRange6 As Range, multiplerange As Range
        Set sourceRange1 = shtSource.Range("B" & cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Row, "I" & cb.TopLeftCell.Row)
        Set sourceRange1 = sourceRange1.Resize(cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count)
        
        Set sourceRange2 = shtSource.Range("K" & cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Row, "M" & cb.TopLeftCell.Row)
        Set sourceRange2 = sourceRange2.Resize(cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count)
        
        Set sourceRange3 = shtSource.Range("P" & cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Row, "R" & cb.TopLeftCell.Row)
        Set sourceRange3 = sourceRange3.Resize(cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count)
        
        Set sourceRange4 = shtSource.Range("Y" & cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Row, "AB" & cb.TopLeftCell.Row)
        Set sourceRange4 = sourceRange4.Resize(cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count)
        
        Set sourceRange5 = shtSource.Range("AF" & cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Row, "AG" & cb.TopLeftCell.Row)
        Set sourceRange5 = sourceRange5.Resize(cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count)
        
        Set sourceRange6 = shtSource.Range("AI" & cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Row, "AJ" & cb.TopLeftCell.Row)
        Set sourceRange6 = sourceRange6.Resize(cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count)
        
        Set multiplerange = Application.Union(sourceRange1, sourceRange2, sourceRange3, sourceRange4, sourceRange5, sourceRange6)
        
        multiplerange.Copy  ' copy and paste the range
        CopyObjectsWithCells = True
        
        
        ' Paste formatting and column widths
        With wsDest.Cells(destRow, "B").Resize(, multiplerange.Columns.Count)
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        End With
        
        destRow = destRow + multiplerange.Rows.Count ' increment the destination row
        
    End If
Next cb

Application.CutCopyMode = False ' clear the clipboard


multiplerange.Copy
With wsDest.Cells(destRow, "B").Resize(, multiplerange.Columns.Count)
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        End With

Set wsDest = Nothing
Set wbDest = Nothing
Set shtSource = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: "So If I select item 1,2,3,4 it ports over the rows in completely wrong order 2,3,4,1" Are you saying they should be copied over in the order they were selected, or always in row order top to bottom?  It's not clear what should happen if you select checkboxes in the order (eg) 3,1,2,4

Comment: "certain columns can be hidden" - is it known in advance which columns these might be?  Are blocks of columns hidden or could it be a single column hidden within a block?

Comment: @TimWilliams I would be okay with either. I think order selected might be out of my scope of knowledge, but I've tried to minimum have it in order from top to bottom and can't figure it out. Right now it's just total random chaos.

Comment: Also, yes it is known in advance. It will always be columns AE:AJ that are either visible or hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out - tested and seems to work for me.
If you run into any problems then I can help if you're willing to share an example workbook with the source sheet (suitably redacted)

**EDIT**: removed the code for sorting the checkboxes - apparently not needed and you can build the range of rows to be copied directly...

**EDIT2**: added a straight copy to pull over any images on the rows. See `###`

Fixed the issue with Q:T - that was due to the `.Offset(3)` being thrown off because there were merged cells in the column headers.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub copySelected()
    'Upon clicking export to customer button, specific ranges and checked box values in column T are exported to new workbook
    Dim shtSource As Worksheet
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet, rngCopy As Range, arr, i As Long, bDoWidths As Boolean
    Dim cb As CheckBox, arrCols As Variant, addr, rngCols As Range
    Dim destRow As Long, stdOps, stdOpsPlusWidths, rws As Range, numRows As Long, rngDest As Range
    Dim colCB As Collection, CopyRows As Range
    
    Set shtSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RFQ FORM INT") 'where the data is
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")
    wsDest.Parent.Windows(1).Zoom = 70

    'build a range of all data rows to be copied
    For Each cb In shtSource.CheckBoxes
        If cb.Value = 1 Then
            BuildRange CopyRows, cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.EntireRow
        End If
    Next cb
    
    'typical pastespecial operations
    stdOps = Array(xlPasteFormats, xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)
    stdOpsPlusWidths = Array(xlPasteColumnWidths, xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, xlPasteFormats)

    DoCopy shtSource.Range("A1:F12"), wsDest.Range("A1"), stdOps
    DoCopy shtSource.Range("G10:H10"), wsDest.Range("R11"), Array(xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)
    
    'set of columns to be copied over
    arrCols = Array("B:I", "K:M", "P:S", "Y:AB", "AF:AG", "AI:AJ")
    
    'begin copying.....
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True        '###
    Set rngDest = wsDest.Range("B12")              'first paste location
    For i = LBound(arrCols) To UBound(arrCols)     'loop array of column addresses
        Set rngCols = shtSource.Range(arrCols(i))
        If Not rngCols.EntireColumn.Hidden Then    'columns not hidden?
            Set rngCopy = Application.Intersect(rngCols, _
                           shtSource.Range("12:14"))  'get the header range (note always 12:14)
            
            DoCopy rngCopy, rngDest, stdOpsPlusWidths 'copy headers over
            
            Set rngCopy = Application.Intersect(rngCols, CopyRows)
            
            DoCopy rngCopy, wsDest.Cells(15, rngDest.Column) '### straight copy first
            
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False '### suppress "there's already data here..." pop-up
            DoCopy rngCopy, wsDest.Cells(15, rngDest.Column), Array(xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)  'copy data over
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            
            Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(, rngCopy.Columns.Count) 'next paste position
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub

'Perform a copy from `rngSrc` to `rngDest`
'If array `arrOps` is provided, then perform a copy/pastespecial for each item in `arrOps`
Sub DoCopy(rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range, Optional arrOps As Variant = Empty)
    Dim op
    Debug.Print "copying " & rngSrc.Address(False, False) & _
                " to " & rngDest.Address(False, False)
    If IsEmpty(arrOps) Then
        rngSrc.Copy Destination:=rngDest 'straight copy
    Else
        rngSrc.Copy
        For Each op In arrOps
            rngDest.PasteSpecial op  'apply each operation from arrOps
        Next op
    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

'build up the range `rngTot` by adding `rngAdd` to it
Sub BuildRange(ByRef rngTot As Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If rngTot Is Nothing Then
        Set rngTot = rngAdd
    Else
        Set rngTot = Application.Union(rngTot, rngAdd)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @Tim first off, thank you. I ran through the code and it appreciate you sourcing where some of the code was adapted from.

I edit the code on a Mac, since some people in our company use Macs. By doing that, as long as it works in mac, it works in PC (not always the other way around). 

- The data is copying over, but two errors. The "paste column widths" is causing an error "There's already data here, do you want to replace it?" This same issue came up in my first code. So I moved that column width to the last step after completing all operations....

Comment: The second issue I cannot show as it requires a photo. In the new document, row Q:T is offsetting by 1 row for me. Here is the source practice sheet for you to take a look at. I will disable some of the conditional format features so that you can just look at the sheets when you open the document. 

https://veritiv.box.com/s/bmhp64bkbfm3nqlg1yr89ec3li81ndk1

Comment: "row Q:T" do you mean column Q:T ?

Comment: Sorry, correct. Columns Q:T. This is what is happening to the copied rows. They are offset by 1 just in this area: https://veritiv.box.com/s/7pqkvu8378jsoxxdlxgempsc68jt2u0s

Comment: See edits above.  Seems to work OK for me, but I don't have a Mac to test on.

Comment: you're a genius and tremendously appreciate the improvements. Works perfectly now in mac as well. The photos don't copy over in column F, but they never did in my code either. And that's a separate topic anyway. Thank you 

Comment: OK glad to hear that fixed it for you.  If I get a chance I will look at the pictures and how they might be copied.

Comment: I messed with this a little and tried setting it as an object to copy over, no success. Is this worthy of it's own thread? My guess is that this question has been asked, but the merged cells row by row are the challenge.

Comment: See my edits above.